# Firebase bug? or Android Studio bug?

Tags: android, firebase

when i use firebase to test project, if use 
`compile com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4`  or 
`compile com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4`

it will cause `default activity not found` exception.

it's my operation:

1. create a new Android project with AandroidStudio-3.0.1,gradle-4.1(build tool:3.0.1);
2. create a new baseFeature module(feature-base);
3. change "app" module apply from "com.android.application" to "com.android.feature" and add api project(":feature-base") on "app" module build.gradle;
4. create a new module(Test-Apk) "phone&tablet" and add api project(":app") to "Test-Apk" build.gradle file;
5. add api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4" or "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4" to feature-base module's build.gradle. it will cause Test-Apk Module default activity not found, it will be all right when i delete "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4" or "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4" dependencies.

what's problem? how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

> "default activity not found" exception

**ANS** : You for got to add `<intent-filter>` to Your activity

[**`<intent-filter>`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) Specifies the types of intents that an activity, service, or broadcast receiver can respond to. An intent filter declares the capabilities of its parent component — what an activity or service can do and what types of broadcasts a receiver can handle.

just add `category.LAUNCHER` & `action.MAIN`  in **`<intent-filter>`** like below code

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>    
  </activity>
```

Comment: on my step, I create a new android project(AS auto add "android.intent.action.MAIN" and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" on my activity), not for this reason.  look at the 5 step desc, it will be all right when delete firebase dependencies,